# NULL guiReceiver 'cvCreateTrackbar2' Error on OpenCV (c++)

Tags: c++, opencv

```
int LOW_H = 0;
int HIGH_H = 255;
createTrackbar("Low Hue", "Trackbar", &LOW_H, HIGH_H);
```

I am getting
**error: (-27:Null pointer) NULL guiReceiver (please create a window) in function 'cvCreateTrackbar2'**

But I already created a window by using those 2 strings, didn't I?

Comment: No, you haven't created the window. The second parameter specifies which window to attach the trackbar to.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#gaf78d2155d30b728fc413803745b67a9b) and error message, you should *create the window* with **`namedWindow`** **before** using the `createTrackbar` function. So your code should become as follows:

```
int LOW_H = 0;
int HIGH_H = 255;
cv::namedWindow("Trackbar",0);
createTrackbar("Low Hue", "Trackbar", &LOW_H, HIGH_H);
```

Comment: The second argument is the name of the window to attach it to

Comment: You are right sorry for mistake